# How to read variables' names python

Tags: python

Can anyone help me with how to read variables' names here:

```
cactus_6 = "values"
cactus_5 = "are"
cactus_4 = "not"
cactus_3 = "relevant"
cactus_2 = "right"
cactus_1 = "now"
```

I need this to create a list consisting of those variables

Comment: It is best you use a dictionary here. Rather than return all your global variables.

Comment: What do you mean "to read variables' names"?  If one reads `cactus_6` its variable name is `cactus_6` and its value is `"values"`.

Comment: I see I'll use dictionary then.

Comment: I mean to read the names of variables, i.e: cactus_1

Comment: There is no need to. Its name is `cactus_1`.

Comment: I think the intent here is to have key, value pairs. Where you can register keys through a dictionary without manually declaring variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're *sure* this is what you want:

```
cacti = [value for name, value in vars().items() if name.startswith('cactus_')]
```

It's probably better just to use a `list`:

```
cacti = ['values', 'are', 'not', 'relevant', 'right', 'now']
```

or `dict`ionary in the first place, though:

```
{
    1: 'values',
    2: 'are',
    3: 'not',
    4: 'relevant',
    5: 'right',
    6: 'now',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on what you want but i'll give it a shot!  You want to create a list consisting of those variables?

If you only have six you could do something like this.

```
list = []
list.append(cactus_1)
list.append(cactus_2)
list.append(cactus_3)
list.append(cactus_4)
list.append(cactus_5)
list.append(cactus_6)
```

This will give you a list that looks like this:

["values",'are','not','relevant','right','now']

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: What I want is to add all variables which have "cactus" in their name to a list without doing a list.append(x) 6 times

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a key-value pair, which is what you get with a dictionary structure.

```
# python

cactus_6 = "values"
cactus_5 = "are"
cactus_4 = "not"
cactus_3 = "relevant"
cactus_2 = "right"
cactus_1 = "now"
```

Becomes:

```
my_cactus_values = {
    "cactus_6": "values",
    "cactus_5": "are",
    "cactus_4": "not",
    "cactus_3": "relevant",
    "cactus_2": "right",
    "cactus_1": "now",
}
```

Then you can loop over them with the `items` method.

```
for name, value in my_cactus_values.items():
    print(name, value)
```

Comment: What if I want to access a specific item from the dictionary using an index?
It gives out an error if I try that:
print(cacti.items()[0])
TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

Comment: Well then you use a list. It's not clear from your question what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, by using a dictionary you can store your keys without having to manually assign them.

The example below provides that:

```
#creates an example list of your values
values = "values are not relevant right now".split() 

#dict comprehension that adds an incremental value to the key name, starting from 1
cactuses = {'cactus{}'.format(idx):val for idx,val in enumerate(values,1)}
cactuses

{'cactus1': 'values',
 'cactus2': 'are',
 'cactus3': 'not',
 'cactus4': 'relevant',
 'cactus5': 'right',
 'cactus6': 'now'}
```

By using enumerate here with a start point from 1, it adds incrementally based on the length of items in your list, appends it to your `cactus` key and then stores its value through a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `eval()`. Something like this …

```
cactus_6 = "values"
cactus_5 = "are"
cactus_4 = "not"
cactus_3 = "relevant"
cactus_2 = "right"
cactus_1 = "now"
cmd = '[' + ','.join(["cactus_%s" % x for x in range(1,7)]) + ']'
eval(cmd)
['now', 'right', 'relevant', 'not', 'are', 'values']
```